# Is there any way to load data directly from snowflake to oracle?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-rds

I am trying to load data from snowflake to oracle directly.
Tried with feature like s3 integration. But it's not supporting to load data from .csv/.txt/.xls files to target table. Let me know if there is a way to load data directly without any third party tools.
Source is snowflake and target is Oracle RDS.
Let me know if any possible way to achieve this connection.

Thanks

Comment: If the data is in S3 you should be able to load it into Oracle using sqlloader, as decribed here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/integrating-amazon-rds-for-oracle-with-amazon-s3/. You can get it into S3 from Snowflake by running a COPY INTO command

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the suggestion!!!

I would like to know is it possible to load millions of data using SQLLDR as mentioned?
And can we use python to build pipeline tasks between Snowflake to Oracle RDS to load data from snowflake to oracle RDS?

Comment: In theory, yes to both your questions